# activity diagram analyse and how to work with

Tags: uml, diagrams, staruml

i need to draw activity diagram to a case and i start with the black circle and make the main swimlane but i didnt understand how to put the action states and the decisions and how to analyse the case and draw the activity diagram

the case is :
non-standard products requested by customers. All non-standard products require a quotation (initial price) before any order can be placed. The quotation generation process starts when a customer requests a quotation, and a member of the Sales Team prepares the quotation using their knowledge. As part of generating a quotation, the Sales Team member checks with the Production System that the product is feasible to manufacture and that the capacity exists to supply the product. If a requested product cannot be supplied, then the customer is informed, otherwise, the salesperson calculate quotation, then issue quotation and reference number at the end the customer receive quotation. Once a quotation is supplied, a quotation remains valid for 30 days and the customer can raise repeat orders against the same quotation. At the end of 30 days the quotation becomes invalid and the customer must seek a new quotation if they wish to place a further order for the same product.

from the above case we take here 3 swimlanes they are :
separate responsibilities of customer, salesperson, and Production System

can any budy help me

thanks

Answer (score 1):

According your question the best way to describe this activity is to use the sequence diagram since there are some objects which interconnect to each other.

The activity diagram is good when there is only one control flow and only one actor. Swimlanes can be used of course, but not in your case.

Also you can use the state chart diagram to show some special conditions like "At the end of 30 days ...".